# Only part of char array being printed with function

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I tried writing a function to print a char array but for some reason, it only prints out part of the function to the console. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void printString(char s[])
{
    int size = sizeof(s) - 1;

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(s + i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char fruit[] = "Cherry";
    printString(fruit);
}
```

leads to the following output:

```
Che
```

Regardless of the word I use, only 3 characters print. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ironically, using just `cout << s;` would work.

Comment: @Bo Can we have the dupe please ;-) (You are so incredibly good with these)

Comment: @Bo Great, thanks a lot. Put a +1 to mark the question as signpost.

Answer (score 4):

> Regardless of the word I use, only 3 characters print. Any help would be appreciated.

`int size = sizeof(s) - 1;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Since `s` [decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) at the function call, `sizeof(s)` always gives you the size of a pointer - 1 (seems to be 32 bit pointers == 4 byte in your case).

Use `size_t size = strlen(s);` instead:

```
void printString(char s[]) {
    size_t size = strlen(s);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << *(s + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
void printString(char *s)
{
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        cout << *s;
        s++ ;
    }
}
```

Or, You may edit your code as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void printString(char s[])
{
    int size = strlen(s);

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(s + i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char fruit[] = "Cherry";
    printString(fruit);
}
```

Comment: Minor niggle: `strlen` does not return `int`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the following line:

```
int size = sizeof(s) - 1;
```

Since you are using function to print your char array, the char array:

```
char fruit[] = "Cherry";
```

decays to a pointer, so `sizeof (s)` is equivalent of `sizeof (char*)`, which, in your configuration is 4-bytes, so the value of `size` becomes equal to 3.

To solve this issue you need to pass the size of the array to your function as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void printString(char s[], int size) // Change here
{
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(s + i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char fruit[] = "Cherry";
    printString(fruit, sizeof(fruit) / sizeof (fruit[0]) - 1); // Change here
}
```

And even then, you would need to use such constructs as `sizeof(fruit) / sizeof (fruit[0])` to return true size of your array, since `sizeof` returns the variable size in **bytes**, so while it would work with `char` (since the size of a `char` is one byte, it may not work for other types of arrays (e.g. `int` arrays).

**Update:** In case of `char` arrays, you need to reduce the size you are trying to print by 1, since string literals (or C-like strings in general - char arrays) end with NULL character (`char` which has value equal to 0), which is the mechanism, by which the end of a string is known. You don't actually need to print it.

Comment: Will try to print the terminating null.

Comment: Looks like a weird fix, but well ...

Comment: @user4581301 Good point, I was thinking of `char[]` as of a regular array, and the thought of the terminating null completely slipped my mind. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, I tried to explain to the OP why he got incorrect output, and how to fix his code with minimal changes required.